# Not authorized deletion for CRUD

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mern

I am trying to make a feature where a user can delete an expense they created OR a manager can delete an expense they have created but I am getting a not authorized error when trying to delete my expense I just created

Expense Controller Delete

```
export const deleteExpense = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const expense = await Expense.findById(req.params.id);
    if (!expense) return error404(req, res, next);

    // Retrieve the user making the request
    const requestingUser = await User.findById(req.userId);
    if (!requestingUser) return error404(req, res, next);

    // Check if the user is authorized to delete the expense
    if (req.userId !== expense.userID && requestingUser.role !== "manager")
      return error403(req, res, next);

    const deletedExpense = await Expense.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id);

    if (!deletedExpense) return res.status(404).send("House not found");
    res.status(200).json({ message: "deleted" });
  } catch (error) {
    errorServer(error, req, res, next);
  }
};
```

jwt middleware

```
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import createError from "http-errors";

export const verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.cookies.accessToken;

  if (!token) return next(createError(401, "You are not authenticated!"));

  jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_KEY, async (err, payload) => {
    if (err) return next(createError(403, "Token is not valid!"));

    req.userId = payload.id;
    req.role = payload.role;

    next();
  });
};
```

Comment: _"I am getting a not authorized error"_... like from `createError(401, "You are not authenticated!")`?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem's solution is in your question only

> where a user can delete an expense they created OR a manager can delete an expense they have created

So the below line can be changed to handle your conditions.

```
if (req.userId !== expense.userID || requestingUser.role !== "manager")
```

Just check whether its working or not as its totally dependent on your functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be clear about what do you mean by "...getting a not authorized error".

If you mean that you're getting the `You are not authenticated!` error from the `createError` instance, then that is most probably because your request is not adding the `accessToken` inside the request body.

If that's not the case, then probably you need to update the following condition based on your functionality:

```
if (req.userId !== expense.userID && requestingUser.role !== "manager")
```